# Predict which user will buy with an offer - discount

Tags: predictive-modeling

I have historical data from an e-shop transactions. I want to write a prediction model and check if a specific user will buy with or without a discount, so I can do some targeting offers.

The idea is:

1. If a user will buy the regular price, will not have an offer.
2. If a user will not buy the regular price, check if he/she will buy with an offer.

With this way, I will avoid to make an offer to someone who would buy with the regular price.

So, I am still in the brainstorming and trying to find a way for implementing the 1-2. Should I create two separate models to predict the 1) and then the 2) with the second model? Or should I join both in one prediction model?

Comment: Did any of the answer below help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Decision trees for a single model prediction for both the set of users.

A good start would be to first [read up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree) on Decision Trees and their applications.

You can include the offer as a decision(as a boolean in this case).

`buying with offer` and `buying without offer` can be the decision criterion.

You can, in fact go ahead and put in the offer values also. For example,

`offer>10%` and `offer <10%`

Comment: Sounds reasonable since I have the same data for both cases. However I am not sure how it will work for users that haven't seen an offer before. Neither accept or reject one. I was hoping to do it through similar users with about the same features. Is it possible with decision trees?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  Please look up the _read up_ hyperlink in the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I was on my phone and didn't see that there was a link on your answer. I will check it and if it actually makes sense, I will choose it as the best answer :)...Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements suggest you might want to use [uplift Modelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uplift_modelling). This has a neat R package references in the wiki article.

[This](http://stochasticsolutions.com/pdf/sig-based-up-trees.pdf) looks like a practical paper.